# Create the new column based on the condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe following format

If user purchases a new item he get unique `id` value, if same user bought another item then `child` column have the previous `id`.

`df <- data.frame(id= c('s123','s1004','s1009','s1010'),child = c("",'s123','s1004',""))`

```
> df
     id child
1  s123      
2 s1004  s123
3 s1009  s1004
4 s1010
```

Now I want to create the new column as `parent` and have the initial id value

```
expect_df <- data.frame(id= c('s123','s1004','s1009','s1010'),child = c("",'s123','s1004',""),parent = c('s123','s123','s123','s1010'))

> expect_df

     id child parent
1  s123         s123
2 s1004  s123   s123
3 s1009 s1004   s123
4 s1010        s1010
```

Comment: why is 3rd parent  s123 and not s1004?

Comment: @AndreElrico because it originates from s123

Comment: Here 3rd row s1009 is mapping s1004 and s1004 is mapping s123

Comment: Yes @AdamWarner

Comment: Could you describe what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m=function(x,df){
   n=with(df,child[x==id])
   ifelse(is.na(n),x, m(n,df))
 }
transform(df,parent=sapply(id,m,df1),row.names=NULL)
     id child parent
1  s123  <NA>   s123
2 s1004  s123   s123
3 s1009 s1004   s123
4 s1010  <NA>  s1010
5 s1103 s1009   s123
```

Answer (score 1):

data: (make sure your input entrys are `characters` and **NOT** `factors`, make sure your `""` are `NA`)

```
df <- data.frame(id= c('s123','s1004','s1009','s1010'),child = c(NA,'s123','s1004',NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

code:

```
df$parent <- NA

repeat {
    sid <- df$id[which(is.na(df$parent))[1]]

    df$parent[apply(df,1,function(x){x<-na.omit(x);if(any(x%in%sid)){sid<<-c(sid,x);T;}else{F}})] <- sid[1]

    if (all(!is.na(df$parent))) break
}
```

result:

```
#      id child parent
# 1  s123  <NA>   s123
# 2 s1004  s123   s123
# 3 s1009 s1004   s123
# 4 s1010  <NA>  s1010
```